# Как передать в проект Java ссылку на подключение к БД из файла Docker-compose или из Dockerfile?

Tags: java, docker, spring-mvc, java-ee, docker-compose

Есть проект Java собирающийся в war-архив. Этот проект пишу у себя на ПК под Windows, поэтому в настройках подключения к БД прописано следующее:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_users?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Пытаюсь запустить в Docker container, монтирую директорию с war-архивом в контейнер. Для этого загрузил 3 образа: tomcat:9.0.39-jdk11-openjdk; mysql; adminer.

Написал следующий YAML-файл для Docker-compose (не уверен, что верный):

```
services:
 
  authorizationService:
    image: tomcat  
    volumes:
        - E:\Authorization_service_prjct\war_arсhive:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
    ports:
        - "8888:8080"
    links:
        - "database:db_users"
  
  database:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: db_users
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
 
  PhpMyAdmin:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "8181:8080"
    links:
        - database:mysql
```

В этом файле для доступа сервиса с приложением authorizationService к БД создал ссылку:

```
links:
        - "database:db_users"
```

Теперь для подключения к БД моя строка подключения в приложении по идее должна выглядеть вот так:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/db_users?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Но я этого сделать не могу потому что собираю war-фрхив у себя на ПК под Windows и ведь для того чтобы он нормально собрался и запустился в строке подключения должно быть
`mysql://localhost:3306`, а не `mysql://database:3306`

Как при формировании образов или запуске контейнеров передать в проект Java ссылку на подключение к БД из файла Docker-compose или из Dockerfile?

Comment: Используйте переменные окружения.

Comment: Слышал про такое, но как это делается? Можете пример привести или ссылку на пример дать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, так:

```yaml
services:
  authorizationService:
    #...
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/db_users?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: Это мы создали переменную среды и присвоили ей значение. А как её использовать в проекте? Как прописать в файле application.properties, что значение `pring.datasource.url` нужно взять из SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL?

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir насколько я понял спринг сам загружает переменные окружения (с большим приорететом чем файл) https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: т.е. мне нужно в `application.properties` создать переменную `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, которой присвоить текущею строку подключения, далее свойству `spring.datasource.url=SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` присвоить эту переменную. А когда я буду деплоить приложения в контейнере, то значение этой переменной возьмется из переменной среды и все должно быть нормально. Один момент я что-то туплю и не могу найти как создать в файле `application.properties` переменную (без успешно гуглил)?

Comment: В appliation.properties вы используете переменную окружения: spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:default}. Через двоеточие можете указать значение по умолчанию, в случае, если переменная не определена.

Comment: @Bakhuss не так. Если в `application.properties` опеределена переменная `spring.datasource.url`, то `SPRING_DATASOURCE.URL` в переменных окружения значение из `application.properties` переопределит без никаких дополнительных действий. Если в окружении нет - используется из properties файла, если есть - то из окружения. Порядок поиска в доке по ссылке https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html В данном случае действуют пункт 10 и 15.

Comment: @Roman Konoval, т.е. `SPRING_DATASOURCE.URL` - это стандартная переменная для spring, которую spring будет всегда искать в среде и если находит, то присваивает автоматически её значение `spring.datasource.url`?

Comment: Да. Только с подчеркиваниями. И это работает для всех переменных. Если есть переменная `a.b.c.d` , то переменная из среды `A_B_C_D` ее заместит. Собственно переменной является `spring.datasource.url`. Именно ее использует spring при создании `DataSource`. Но в переменных окружения точки не на всех платформах поддерживаются, поэтому ищется с заменой точек на подчеркивания.

Comment: @Roman Konoval, а если все-таки укажу вот так - `spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:default}`, это сработает или нет. Просто это выглядит более наглядно и понятно при чтении кода

Comment: Не знаю. Т.к. это абсолютно не нужно, то никогда не пробовал.

Comment: В случае, когда переменная есть в окружении, скорее всего сработает, но совершенно по другой причине. Потому, что спринг не будет в properties файл смотреть вообще. Он просто возьмет значение из окружения, по уже описанному выше алгоритму поиска значения переменной. А вот когда, переменная не задана в окружении - нужно пробовать.

Comment: Такая запись тоже работает.